# Cookie is null with IE using C#, but not for firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I wrote sometime an application with C# and ASP, now I made a small change that has nothing to do with cookies and it's not creating the cookies for IE, but it's creating them for Firefox.

From my login.aspx:

```
            HttpCookie cLevel = new HttpCookie("Level");
            cLevel.Value = consulta.retornarNivel(Login2.UserName, Login2.Password).ToString();
            cNivel.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            cNivel.Domain = Request.Url.Host.ToString();
            HttpCookie cUser = new HttpCookie("User");
            cUser.Value = Login2.UserName;
            cUser.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
            cUser.Domain = Request.Url.Host.ToString();


            //create cookies..
            Response.Cookies.Add(cLevel);
            Response.Cookies.Add(cUser);

            //redirect to Services
            Response.Redirect("Services.aspx");
```

Now for my Services.aspx, on my page_load I have this line:

```
    lbWelcome.Text = "Welcome" + Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["User"].Value);
```

This line on IE gives me: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
While on Firefox it parses perfectly.

What could be affecting my code with FF?

Comment: Why are you even bothering to set the domain? It will naturally be valid for the response url, so setting the domain itself might be the culprit - IE may not be responding to that well.

Comment: Are you certain that the cookie isn't being created, but has no value? That is, have you verified that Login2.UserName is populated when you assign that as the value to the cookie? That would cause the same error - the Value property being passed to HtmlEncode would be null.

Comment: The cookie is being created on Login2_Authenticate() event, first I check if it's not empty and if it's valid by SQL, after that it creates the cookie

Comment: Ok, I did cthe change Tejs mentioned, compiled and it still not working on the production server... for IE.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't my code, it was the server it had another time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Seting the cookies with the server's time is the worst way. if client got the different time, What do you think it will happen.